# Moved Wordpress site to new server, directory permissions not working correctly

Tags: directory, permissions, server

I built a Wordpress on my hosting space and then transferred it my clients server - followed all the instructions and pretty much everything works fine.

The ONLY problem I have is that the directory permissions aren't working correctly, they're all set correctly (generally 755) - but I cannot update/install plugins and cannot upload media.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: What are the owner/group settings on the directories and what is the user/group of the web server?

Comment: Everything is set as per the Wordpress instructions (checked yesterday) so directories are 755. 

I don't have access to the server, I'm working for a client who's IT department run the server and just give me access to the files and Mysql for this particular website.

So I can only see the root of the website, no higher.